# hot reload in jekyll not working

Tags: html, browser, workflow, jekyll, auto-generate

I've installed jekyll 3.1.6 on Mint 17 (ubuntu 14.4) with
ruby 2.2 + python 2.7
My browsers are Chromium and Firefox

I think I've tried every trick I can find on the internet, but it still won't auto-reload, even though the terminal does say that auto-regeneration has been enabled and with each file content change and save, the terminal logs the change and tells me it's been done. But I'm still forced to refresh a page manually to see the changes.

Open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jekyll auto-generation future(Using `jekyll server`) automatically change/modify the files on **_site folder only**, it does not refresh browser windows automatically, you have to use grunt for that. There are already many of [NPM packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-reload) and [Repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-livereload) for that.

Comment: wow. all this time i thought that jekyll would refresh the browser as well. what a waste of frustration. i did find a gem someone created called *hawkins* that is supposed to add a new `liveserve` jekyll command that refreshes the browser for you, but it didn't work for me. I will try try the options suggested here.

Comment: @DavidJacquel thanks for the link, that worked out perfectly! The only tip I might add to the great instructions on that page--if you weren't already familiar with gulp/grunt--is that the gulpfile.js goes in the root of the directory/folder you have your project in.

Answer (score 1):

execute

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload
```

execute

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000
```